# Where is my blond friend going?

Tags: cipher

My blond friend must have been in quite a hurry when he sent me an email telling me he was going to

aajooesfroeaajos

I was initially confused, but then I realized what he meant. Where was he going?

Hint:

> Where are blond people from?

Comment: Have you considered https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do ?

Comment: Why are you asking us if you already know when he is going?

Comment: There is a lot to go on.

Comment: Regarding the hint... Blond people come from *a lot* of places, [Wikipedia has a large list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blond#Geographic_distribution)....

Comment: Knowing the solution, I still think there is not enough to go on. Blond people come from a lot of places, as Beastly Gerbil said...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your blond friend, who is from Scandinavia, is going to

> Philadelphia.

There are three extra letters at the end of the alphabets used in Scandinavian countries. In Norway and Denmark, the three extra letters are Ææ, Øø and Åå. In Sweden, they are Ää, Öö and Åå. They are often transliterated like this in character sets that lack them:

- æ/ä: ae
- ø/ö: oe
- å: aa

So substituting transliterations for their Scandinavian counterparts in your friend's message, we get

> "åjoøsfrøåjos" (Norwegian/Danish) or "åjoösfröåjos" (Swedish)

Now, your blond friend is obviously either Norwegian or Swedish, because he has one of these two keyboard layouts on his computer (Denmark has a different one):

[image: Norwegian keyboard layout]
[image: Swedish keyboard layout]

And, in a hurry, he touch-typed without looking at his keyboard, with his fingers one key to the right of the ones he intended to strike. Therefore,

> "philadelphia" became "åjoøsfrøåjos" or "åjoösfröåjos", and then somehow transliterated to "aajooesfroeaajos" through some magical piece of software for representing non-ASCII character sets in ASCII (or something).

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: @Improve Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Longshot:

> Hurried blonde friend writes: 
>  **Ios free ios** (phonetic interpretation of the cipher) 
>  And rushes of to the local Apple Store

Comment: Cool idea, but not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might be onto something. EDIT: I am not.

> This is tagged cipher. If your Rot11, you get most of the letters to "puzzle": lluzzpdqczplluzd I initially tried to think of what letter might start a word with 2 of itself and thought of the Welsh double L consonant and rotated on that point. It doesn't seem to fit but we do have "puzzl" which seems more than coincidence given our site name.

I'm not sure what to do here or if I've just found a happy little accident.

Comment: Amazingly, this is a coincidence.

Comment: Well... ok then.